# Common object in two objects java

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am implementing one api and I have the following request bodies for 2 different endpoints:

endpoint1:

```
 {
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "123"
    }
  ]
}
```

endpoint2:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "variable": "stack"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to build a common object for these 2 in java spring application?

Comment: You can do it easily, but the question is: do you want? Functionally speaking, the first object contains an id, the second a variable. Even if they happen to look alike, they are not guaranteed to be in the future. I wouldn't refactor into a common object.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by a "common object". If everything (or "enough" things) include an array of `requests` it'd make *more* sense to wrap up the requests collection *in* the object that has a collection of `requests`. Whether or not it's meaningful to do so depends on your specific requirements.

Comment: I meant a common model for accepting the request body, if that makes sense